# Can't create quickform via CRM_Core_Form in my custom extension

Tags: extension, quickform, custom

I want to create page with form via my custom extension. I find this page in documentation: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/quickform/
But when I create a class according to the documentation, I get this error:

```
Error: Call to a member function setName() on string in CRM_Core_Form->__construct() (line 271 of /var/www/mvp1/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php).
```

My class:

```
class CRM_JosiahVenture_Page_RolePrimaryAlert extends CRM_Core_Form {

  public function preProcess() {
  }

  public function buildQuickForm() {
    $this->add('text', 'my_text_field', ts('Enter Some Text'));
  }

  public function addRules() {
    $this->addFormRule(array('CRM_Example_Form', 'myRules'));
  }

  public static function myRules($values) {
    $errors = array();
    if ($values['foo'] != 'abc') {
      $errors['foo'] = ts('You entered the wrong text!');
    }
    return empty($errors) ? TRUE : $errors;
  }

  public function postProcess() {
  }
}
```

My xml file:

```
<item>
    <path>civicrm/RolePrimary</path>
    <page_callback>CRM_JosiahVenture_Page_RolePrimaryAlert</page_callback>
    <title>CustomActivity</title>
    <access_arguments>access CiviCRM</access_arguments>
  </item>
```

Tpl file is empty for now.

Comment: Are you using url civicrm/RolePrimary?reset=1&action=add ?

Comment: @PradeepNayak yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is not connected to your issue, but if you implement a form, it supposed to be inside a `Form` directory, and the class name should follow this (has to contain `_Form_`). In your case the class name contains the `_Page_` string which is strange. I would like to suggest you to [generate](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-form) the basics of your form with the [`civix` tool](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/). After the file generation you can check that the dummy form works well or not. If it works well, you can start to modify the dummy code.

Comment: Thank you! I am stupid... I put it in wrong location... I had created a page and I transform it to the form. It is neccessery that the form is in form directory. And also civix will help with this.

Answer (score 0):

In preprocess/postprocess/buildquickform, you should call the parent, i.e. your class should be:

```
class CRM_JosiahVenture_Page_RolePrimaryAlert extends CRM_Core_Form {

  public function preProcess() {
    parent::preProcess(); // <-- ************ add this
  }

  public function buildQuickForm() {
    parent::buildQuickForm();  // <-- ************ and this
    $this->add('text', 'my_text_field', ts('Enter Some Text'));
  }

  public function addRules() {
    $this->addFormRule(array('CRM_Example_Form', 'myRules'));
  }

  public static function myRules($values) {
    $errors = array();
    if ($values['foo'] != 'abc') {
      $errors['foo'] = ts('You entered the wrong text!');
    }
    return empty($errors) ? TRUE : $errors;
  }

  public function postProcess() {
    parent::postProcess();  // <-- ************ and this
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean parent? Do you mean "CRM_Core_Form" from which I extend? Can be more specific please? I want seperate page where preprocess can be empty now, in buildquickform i want 1 input field and in postprocess I want call api3. The most simple form from which I can understand how it works.
I also try make copy of form, which extend "CRM_Core_Form" and I got the same error.

Comment: I'll update my answer more fully.

Comment: Thanks, but this not help :/ Still I get same error..